# Trigger Dropbox to Start Sync

Tags: sync, dropbox

Dropbox 2.6.2 on Ubuntu GNOME 13.03 64bit. When I modified a file on my local disk, under `~/Dropbox/`, Dropbox start to sync immediately. But when modifications are made on the remote space, e.g. creating or renaming or deleting a dir or file, I don't see the change in my local dir very soon.

Any way to trigger Dropbox to start sync right now?

Comment: Please explain what the "remote space" is. Is that a different computer elsewhere? Where is the location of that dropbox? Is it a local disk, or is Dropbox mounted on a network drive?